# Rewriting flow / class component to custom hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to rewrite the following code here which was written in flow to a custom hook. I got stuck and the hook doesn't work as it should. Do you see any mistake I made?

The error I get is `TypeError: elementRefs.ref is not a function`

Here is how I call it:

**parent.js**

```
import MultiRef from "./MultiRef";

const [elementRefs] = useState(() => new MultiRef());
```

Here is my version:

```
function useMultiRef() {
  const map = new Map();
  const _refFns = new Map();

  const ref = (key) => {
    let refFn = _refFns.get(key);
    if (!refFn) {
      refFn = (value) => {
        if (value == null) {
          _refFns.delete(key);
          map.delete(key);
        } else {
          map.set(key, value);
        }
      };
      _refFns.set(key, refFn);
    }
    return refFn;
  };
}

export default useMultiRef;
```

Here is the original code:

```
/* @flow */

type RefFn<V> = (value: V|null) => mixed;

export default class MultiRef<K,V> {
  map: Map<K,V> = new Map();

  _refFns: Map<K,RefFn<V>> = new Map();

  ref(key: K): RefFn<V> {
    let refFn: ?RefFn<V> = this._refFns.get(key);
    if (!refFn) {
      refFn = value => {
        if (value == null) {
          this._refFns.delete(key);
          this.map.delete(key);
        } else {
          this.map.set(key, value);
        }
      };
      this._refFns.set(key, refFn);
    }
    return refFn;
  }
}
```

Update (**parent.js**):

```
/**
 * Scrolls to element if var goToElement is set
 */
useEffect(() => {
  const ref = elementRefs.map.get(goToElement);
  // If no ref exists, scroll to top of the floor instead
  if (!ref) {
    floorRef.current.scrollTop = 0;
    return;
  }
  // Scroll to element: scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord)
  floorRef.current.scrollTo(0, ref.offsetTop);
  // Wait for a short time to perform scrolling
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    // currentElementRef is needed for highlighting the element
    setCurrentElementRef(ref);
  }, 500);

  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, [elementRefs, goToElement]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return `ref` value for `elementRefs.ref` to work, currently, you just run a void function.

Also, **that's not a custom hook** you implemented a simple function.

```
function multiRef() {
  //...
  const ref = (key) => {...};

  return { ref };
}
```

Custom hook should **use hooks**, to get similar properties like a class, it should look something like:

```
function useMultiRef() {
  const map = useRef(new Map());
  const _refFns = useRef(new Map());

  const ref = useCallback((key) => {
    let refFn = _refFns.current.get(key);
    if (!refFn) {
      refFn = (value) => {
        if (value == null) {
          _refFns.current.delete(key);
          map.current.delete(key);
        } else {
          map.current.set(key, value);
        }
      };
      _refFns.current.set(key, refFn);
    }
    return refFn.current;
  }, []);

  return { ref, map };
}

export default useMultiRef;
```

Comment: Hi Dennis, thank you for your answer. In both cases I get the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined`. The error occurs from `const ref = elementRefs.map.get(goToElement);`. (I updated my code above.) It seems like elementRefs is not defined anymore.

Comment: Well, just export map too... I cant know what you are using or what not. Please dont add follow up question if they not related, just add another question.

Comment: Okay understood, thank you. Not 100% sure what you mean with "export map too", but I will try to figure it out. I generate elementRefs out of MultiRef, that's why I thought it is related to my problem (`const [elementRefs] = useState(() => new MultiRef());`)

Comment: If you use `elementRefs.map` so you need to return it too... `{ ref, map}`, I've added it to the answer

Comment: What I meant in "dont add follow up question" is when someone asking about A, then he adds the solution to its code, and says that B not working, altough A is solved, like asked. Cheers.

Comment: Noted, you couldn't know I need that `map`.